# Having built the required APKs using buildozer, is it possible to import these in Android Studio?

Tags: android, python, kivy

I would like to build an application on android which automatically classifies e-mail messages based on their content. The classifier was implemented using TensorFlow, which I know can be ported on an Android device. 
 The preprocessing steps are based on some nltk classes and functions and that is why I had to create an APK from this package (also numpy). 
I would like to ask whether it is possible to import these packages in Android Studio. If so, how? Or shall I implement the application using kivy (instead of using Java and Android Studio)?
I would really appreciate your help, since I've been struggling with solving this issue for a while!

Comment: Theano does not support Android, it might still be possible but will not be easy + efficient, see this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/theano-users/android/theano-users/S6zqdG4lOpw/EOubqu_cS4kJ
I would recommend using TensorFlow if you want to port your application to android.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have implemented the model in tensorflow as well but then, how can I run the script, which is intended to make the necessary preprocessing steps?